# Having problems turning JSON into javascript object

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using jquery and the jquery-json plugin found here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

I've checked at http://jsonlint.com/ to make sure the returned JSON is valid and it is.

I cannot get this function in the jquery-json plugin to return a javascript object. It simply throws an error at JSON.parse(src) on line 118 of the plugin (un-minified).

```
var data = $.evalJSON(rsp);
console.log(data);
```

Where rsp is the response from $.ajax() success callback. Also,

```
typeof rsp // returns object
```

Comment: I suggest trying https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js and posting the string you're struggling with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `rsp` is already an Object then you don't have to parse it.  If `typeof rsp` returned String then you would.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.ajax` method will parse the JSON for you, so you don't have to do that. What's sent to the success callback is already an object.

Also, if you are using jQuery 1.4.1 or later, you don't need a plugin if you would need to parse JSON. It has the `$.parseJSON` method built in.

Answer (score 0):

I've always just used javascript's built in eval() function: `eval('('+rsp+')');` seeing as JSON is literally just a javascript object. (Hence its name: Javascript Object Notation)

Answer (score 0):

`rsp` is already a **javascript object**, since `typeof rsp == 'object'`. You don't need to do anything to it.

If it was a **JSON-encoded string**, then `typeof rsp == 'string'`, and only then would you need `$.evalJSON`.